# Get pair tensor object in Tensor Array

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, python-itertools

I have a problem when getting a pair combination of Tensor array in Tensorflow framework.
I want process similar as with numpy array:
`for x in list(itertools.combinations(features, 2))`
Can anyone guide me  How to get a pair combination of tensor array?
Thank you very much!

Comment: So you have a `tf.TensorArray` and you want to obtain all 2-combinations of its elements? Can you give a bit more of context as to why you need this and how you would use it?

Comment: `features = tf.Variable([0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 9., 10.])`
`features1 = np.array([0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 9., 10.])`
`for x in list(itertools.combinations(features, 2)):`
    `print(x)`
With feature1 is okie, but I want make process with feature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not very efficient (it's quadratic time and space in the number of elements), but it does produce the desired result:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def make_two_combinations(array):
    # Take the size of the array
    size = tf.shape(array)[0]
    # Make 2D grid of indices
    r = tf.range(size)
    ii, jj = tf.meshgrid(r, r, indexing='ij')
    # Take pairs of indices where the first is less or equal than the second
    m = ii <= jj
    idx = tf.stack([tf.boolean_mask(ii, m), tf.boolean_mask(jj, m)], axis=1)
    # Gather result
    return tf.gather(array, idx)

# Test
with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
    features = tf.constant([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
    comb = make_two_combinations(features)
    print(sess.run(comb))
```

Output:

```
[[0 0]
 [0 1]
 [0 2]
 [0 3]
 [0 4]
 [1 1]
 [1 2]
 [1 3]
 [1 4]
 [2 2]
 [2 3]
 [2 4]
 [3 3]
 [3 4]
 [4 4]]
```